# QCombobox bigger in size for the first time only

Tags: resize, widget, pyqt, qcombobox, qstackedwidget

```
class RangeSelection(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self._create_widgets()
        layout.addWidget(self.select_combo, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked, 1, 2, 5, 1)
        self.stacked.currentWidget().setSizePolicy(
                QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.stacked.currentChanged.connect(self.onCurrentChanged)

    def onCurrentChanged(self):
        currentw = self.stacked.currentWidget()
        currentw.adjustSize()
        if currentw == self.releasew:
            currentw.sizeAdjustPolicy = QComboBox.AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow
        self.adjustSize()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        self.stacked = QStackedWidget()
        self.datew = QCalendarWidget()
        self.datew.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.
                                           NoVerticalHeader)
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.datew)
        self.buildidw = QLineEdit()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.buildidw)
        self.releasew = QComboBox()
        self.releasew.addItems([str(k) for k in sorted(releases())])
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.releasew)
        self.revw = QLineEdit()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.revw)

        self.select_combo = QComboBox()
        self.select_combo.addItems(['date', 'buildid', 'release', 'changeset'])
        self.select_combo.activated.connect(self.stacked.setCurrentIndex)
```

I have this code where I am having four widgets in the `QStackedWidget`. When I run this code and change my selection in `self.select_combo` from `date` to `release`, the `self.releasew` combobox initially shows up as same size as that of the `QCalendarWidget`( which obviously looks horrible ). But, when I change my selection from `release` to any other value and then back to `release`, the `self.releasew` combobox shows up in the size it should. Why is this happening? What is the solution to this problem?

Note: I am using `PyQt4`. Also note that widgets for `buildid` and `changeset` do not show any abnormal behaviour.

Comment: have you tried commenting out the AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `setSizePolicy` and `sizeAdjustPolicy` code. I also removed the call to `self.adjustSize()`. This worked. Though, I don't know why.